# POST data using file_get_contents

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf, file-get-contents

I have a form which has to be filled with data from JSON data and the form should be created as pdf using mpdf and send to mail.for that I was using jquery and ajax.

First I used ajax that will send json data to the PHP file.In the PHP file,I am using the following

```
`$json = file_get_contents('php://input');//to getting json post values we need to use
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$obj1=http_build_query($obj);
//print_r($obj);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $obj1
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('PDF_Form.php', false, $context);
echo $result;`
```

The result now is showing  instead of value.Please tell me where is the issue.

I need to place all the post values in the form and then the form should be converted as string to ajax response for creating pdf and send mail.

regards,
rekha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself found the way to solve this problem.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');//to getting json post values we need to use
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
ob_start();
include('PDF_Form.php');
$template_html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $template_html;
```

In the PDF_Form.php file I have used like this...

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <input type="text" name="eg" value="
        <?php echo $obj['status'];?>
           ">

</html>
```

It works perfectly....

Regards,

Rekha